typescript build Vitest node dependency problems
I'm currently migrating a JavaScript project to TypeScript (and this is my first attempt at TS). For some reason, tsc --build throws a bunch of errors for vitest not being able to resolve the node library definitions:
../node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.3.1/node_modules/vite/dist/node/index.d.ts(6,23): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'node:http' or its corresponding type declarations.

There are 17 or so similar errors.
This is my tsconfig.json:
{
    "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.js", "**/*.mjs", "**/*.mts"],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "coverage/**/*",
        "dist/**/*",
        "test/**/*"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "dist",
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "$types/*": [
                "types/*"
            ]
        },
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "NodeNext",
        "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
        "checkJs": true
    }
}

Now, vitest obviously doesn't need any of those files, because the tests all ran and passed when it was pure JS. But now I can't even transpile the base project, let alone run tests. How do I get vitest to either not care about those, or properly find them?
Based on this conversation, I tried setting target to ESNext, but that had no impact. I also tried changing moduleResolution to Bundler — but that both seems like the wrong thing (since, at least for the moment, I'm just trying to get pure tsc to work), and wanted me to make a bunch of other changes.
I also tried setting vitest global types in the tsconfig:
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["vitest/globals"]
  }
}

But that too had no effect.
TBH, I'm not even ready to run tests, as I still have actual typescript errors to work through in my conversion, but I need to get this vitest compile problem out of the way. Any ideas?
For completeness sake, here's my vitest config:
// vitest.config.mjs
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';

export default defineConfig({
    test: {}
});

// vitest.workspace.mjs
import { configDefaults, defineWorkspace } from 'vitest/config';

export default defineWorkspace([
    './*',
    {
        extends: './vitest.config.mjs',
        test: {
            exclude: [
                ...configDefaults.exclude,
                '**/*.component-{test,spec}.{js,mjs,cjs,ts,mts,cts,jsx,tsx'
            ],
            name: 'unit',
            environment: './test/prisma/prisma-test-environment.mjs',
            setupFiles: ['./test/helpers/setup.mjs']
        }
    },
    {
        extends: './vitest.config.mjs',
        test: {
            include: [ '**/*.component-{test,spec}.{js,mjs,cjs,ts,mts,cts,jsx,tsx' ],
            name: 'component',
            environment: './test/prisma/prisma-test-environment.mjs',
            setupFiles: ['./test/helpers/setup.mjs']
        }
    }
]);

Also, in case it matters, this is in a pnpm mono-repo setup, where the layout is
/
/node_modules
/package.json
# main project directory
/package
/package/node_modules
/package/package.json
/package/tsconfig.json
/package/vitest.config.mjs
/package/vitest.workspace.mjs


This is happening because in TypeScript, @types/node is a required dependency of vite. I'm not yet sure if the failure to yell about the missing dependency is a vitest problem or a pnpm problem, and will likely investigate further and make the appropriate PR on GitHub, but, until whichever actually fixes their dependency resolution, the solution is to just manually
pnpm install --save-dev @types/node

